# Shaft Spline Information

Tags: mechanical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering, computer-aided-design, documentation

I have a shaft with splines on it that I want to create a drawing for in Solidworks because I may need to have this specific spline replicated on a part in the future. Does anyone have any documentation on how to identify a spline? Or possibly a table of standard splines used in industry based off of shaft size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the type of spline you're defining, there are different characteristics that you'll need to identify the spline to either a machinist or to the customer who will need to design the mating part. Some of them are pretty straightforward and will be needed regardless of the type of spline, such as physical diameters (major and minor), number of teeth, the class of fit and spline shape (involute, flat, etc.)

For the most basic splines I work with, we can define it with only a major and minor diameter, the number of teeth, and the distance between two parallel tooth edges, because it's a flat side spline. However, something like an involute spline requires more information, such as a pitch diameter, pressure angel, effective tooth width, and distance between pins of a given size. This is because the complex shape makes it impossible to directly measure the spline geometry in a meaningful way, so we require both design dimensions and measurable dimensions. The spline table below is an example for an involute spline - the dimensions listed fully define the spline and allow us to measure it for quality purposes. I would include a table like this on any spline machining print so that you have the information readily available.

[image: Spline Table Example]

If you are using a standard spline, such as a spline defined by ANSI B92.1, you could refer to it on a customer print as just the ANSI standard spline with only the information necessary to locate it in the standards table (should be pressure angle, class of fit, and either number of teeth or pitch diameter.) Then the standard will provide all other information, or the methods to calculate the information necessary to manufacture the spline.

Answer (score 0):

Many "spline" designs around in industry - load dependant etc start with square, then hex, splines 6, 8 and upward, also "lemon" shafts - lots of those used in the agricultural branch.

You need to give some more info : diameter inner and outer, no of splines, length, sliding joint, application etc.

Comment: I guess I'm more curious on being able to label a spline so that the manufacturer knows what I am talking about as in giving it a spec based off of my measurements. I understand the design I just don't know how to relay the measurements based on a standard identifier.

Comment: Diameters, number of splines, size (length, width) of spline and size of gap